# how to retrieve the validation details like valid or invalid transaction of all transactions in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

How to write a function in the chaincode to retrieve all transactions with validation details like valid or invalid in go lang? then I will call it from the peer container using invoke function.

I used getHistoryForKey but the validation details were not returned.

your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The smart contract / chaincode only sees the ledger state, which is only modified by valid transactions. Transactions that do not pass validation are recorded on the blockchain but are not applied to the ledger.

You can obtain all transactions in a client application by using block eventing. The validation code is recorded for each transaction within a block. The [off_line_data](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data) sample demonstrates how block eventing can be used to capture the read/write sets from all valid transactions. This can be easily modified to capture both valid and invalid transactions by just removing the [filtering of valid transactions](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/128950edca6c8f2501e8447228c8c9ccc253ab7a/off_chain_data/application-typescript/src/listen.ts#L141).

Iterating over all the blocks in the blockchain becomes increasingly expensive as the block height increases. You might consider building an off-chain data store to hold the information you need in an easily queryable form, exactly as demonstrated by the [off_line_data](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data) sample.

Comment: I am new to Fabric but what I understood is that we can't use chaincode to view the invalid transactions but we can do it through the client application, right?

Comment: That is correct